# Why is the background not showing up for the entire section

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, frontend, web-frontend

I am trying to figure out why my grey background isn't showing up for the entire section. I have everything embedded inside the section with the id of mid-section. I have the mid-section background color as grey in the css but it is not showing up down the entire screen. How do I get the background color to show down the entire screen?

```
<section id="mid-section">
<div class="pic">
  <img class="pic-image" src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod.s3.amazonaws.com/images/bbq-party-grilled-sausages-1561576780.jpg?crop=1.00xw:0.753xh;0,0.0562xh&resize=1200:*" alt="bbq">
</div>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]"
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551782450-17144efb9c50?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" data-holder-rendered="true">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Best Burgers</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras vulputate laoreet metus non blandit. Sed pretium in arcu ac sollicitudin. Quisque at erat metus. Vivamus id viverra nunc, ac convallis dui. Curabitur lobortis purus sit amet egestas
            egestas. Donec quam nunc, pretium id nibh interdum, malesuada condimentum est. Quisque sed scelerisque mi.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <small class="text-muted"></small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]"
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551782450-17144efb9c50?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" data-holder-rendered="true">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Best Burgers</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras vulputate laoreet metus non blandit. Sed pretium in arcu ac sollicitudin. Quisque at erat metus. Vivamus id viverra nunc, ac convallis dui. Curabitur lobortis purus sit amet egestas
            egestas. Donec quam nunc, pretium id nibh interdum, malesuada condimentum est. Quisque sed scelerisque mi.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <small class="text-muted"></small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6">
      <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
        <img class="card-img-top" data-src="holder.js/100px225?theme=thumb&amp;bg=55595c&amp;fg=eceeef&amp;text=Thumbnail" alt="Thumbnail [100%x225]"
          src="https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1551782450-17144efb9c50?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=800&q=60" data-holder-rendered="true">
        <div class="card-body">
          <h5 class="card-title">Best Burgers</h5>
          <p class="card-text">Aliquam erat volutpat. Cras vulputate laoreet metus non blandit. Sed pretium in arcu ac sollicitudin. Quisque at erat metus. Vivamus id viverra nunc, ac convallis dui. Curabitur lobortis purus sit amet egestas
            egestas. Donec quam nunc, pretium id nibh interdum, malesuada condimentum est. Quisque sed scelerisque mi.</p>
          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
            <small class="text-muted"></small>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

```
.card {
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
}

.card-img-top {
height: 225px;
width: 100%;
display: block;
}


#mid-section {
background-color: #DCDCDC;
}

.pic-image {
display: block;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
width: 85%;
padding-top: 350px;
position: relative;
}

.container {
padding: 50px;
}
```

Comment: `.card { position: relative; }` perhaps? Especially inside a grid system, it doesn't make sense to position them absolute as the container will collapse.

Comment: Thanks Tim that solved it. I appreciate that, i cant believe something so simple stressed me out like this.

Comment: No problem, I've clarified the answer a bit for anyone who needs it. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using a grid sytem, the structure is set for your width. Adding components to the grid, will generate the height. Making `.card` positioned absolute will collapse the height. Therefor, your background color won't be visible or perhaps only for the added padding, since padding generates height as well.

```
.card { position: relative; }
```

Also good to know, with Bootstrap 4, flex-box is introduced, and your structure will now generate the same height across all columns inside a single row. This used to be covered with Equal height calculation in the past but is now obsolete.

```
.card { height: 100% } /*is your equal height*/
```

Even better, with Bootstrap card-deck, you don't need columns anymore. Simply adjust the `flex-basis` in a media query and/or `flex-grow`, `flex-shrink` if you need them to stretch/downsize. This simplifies the structure even more.

Good luck!